# Customer title and description for Facebook share?

Tags: facebook, web, share

I am using the following script to share links with Facebook:

```
<script>function fbs_click() {u=location.href;t=document.title;window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');return false;}</script><a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<url>" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank">Share on Facebook</a>
```

When facebook share screen popup opens it displayes title and description. I want to provide my own title and description of share are there parameters available for this?

Comment: Create a facebook application . 

https://developers.facebook.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Facebook Application at http://developers.facebook.com/

Then embed Open Graph metatags in your document that describe to the Facebook document linter which title, image, description, and URL to use when shared.

[Open Graph Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/)
[Open Graph Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944835/)

Here is an example copied from the Facebook documentation that shows the Open Graph meta tags used to describe a website.

```
<html>
    <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# 
                  website: http://ogp.me/ns/website#">
     <meta property="fb:app_id"               content="YOUR_APP_ID"> 
     <meta property="og:type"                 content="website"> 
     <meta property="og:url"                  content="URL of this object"> 
     <meta property="og:image"                content="URL to an image">
     <meta property="og:title"                content="Name of blog">
     <meta property="og:description"          content="Description of object"> 
    </head>
<body>
    <!--a wonderful website  -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is my website i don't how can i use open graph meta tags ? will it work without facebook app ?

Comment: Not sure if they will work without being related to a valid Facebook Application ID.  Might just give it a try and see if it does, if not just register a Facebook Application, it's free.

Answer (score 0):

See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/ for more detailed view of the Facebook Share.

I think you can change the t= parameter to change the title of your share post on Facebook, not sure if you can change the description, I think the description comes from the meta Description of the page you are sharing.